# Create Table Vertically html css angular

Tags: java, html, css, angular, spring-boot

Hell everybody,

i want to ask you about how i can create a Table but Vertically (as comparative table), which i can show the Data uch like this:

| Info | User1 | User2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Mark | Marke |
| lastName | tommy | Tommi |
| Age | 13 | 25 |

my Problem is if i want to feth the Data from backend it will be showed Horizontally and i want to show it vertically as if i want to compare two customers and check if they have the same data or something deffirent (like age for example).

Can someone help me to do something like it (back + frontend) ?? am sorry fr my question but i have tried toooo much and googled it but i cannot find anything, that can help me to solve this problem.

My Idea from this: i want to fetch the duplication suspicion from backend and show the in the Table and compare them.

Thanks so much for any Idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>info</th>
    <td>User1</td>
    <td>user2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Marke</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>lastname</th>
    <td>tommy</td>
    <td>tommi</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>age</th>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but the data should i fetch them from backend, how can i fetch every user info vertically ?
when i use *ngFor in Angular, it shows me the Data that i fetched them, horizontally.

Comment: What do you mean fetch vertically? fetch is fetch, you just fetch data and that all,  it has nothing to do with how you actually render fetched data. Post the data you are fetching and ngFor you use and i will be able to help